# Is there a way to control the string the user gives with do while in Java?

Tags: java

The user has to give just two strings in my case "AM" or "PM". I have already write the do while(); loop to do that. But when inside while(); I have both expressions the loop becomes infinite. When I have just one no matter which one, the program run perfect. Thanks in advance for any solution!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Time{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    int hours, minutes, sec;
    String period, x, y;


    x = "AM";
    y = "PM";

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Give the values you will be asked. Those values form the time give them in such a way that they would appear in a digital clock. (ex.: 2pm = 14)");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("..............................................");
    do{
        System.out.print("Chooce the current time period (AM or PM) : ");
        period = reader.nextLine();

        if(!period.equals(x) || !period.equals(y)){
            System.out.println("Your input should be AM or PM");
        }
    }while(!period.equals(x) || !period.equals(y));
```

Comment: Since `x` is not equal to `y`, `!period.equals(x) || !period.equals(y)` will never be false. You probably meant `&&`.

Comment: To mark a question as solved, you should [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `while(!period.equals(x) || !period.equals(y));`

In : `while(!period.equals(x) && !period.equals(y));`

You have to put the condition in AND otherwise it is always evaluated as true

is "AM" not equals to "AM" false
is "AM" not equals to "PM" true

true or false = true | (1+0 = 1)

Answer (score 6):

Your condition says

```
while(!period.equals(x) || !period.equals(y));
```

So that means while period is NOT "AM" OR "PM" we should continue.

Let's say we set period to "AM". This is desired, but according to your logic we must continue, even though `period` is "AM", it's also NOT "PM". See the issue?

Try this instead

```
while(!period.equals(x) && !period.equals(y));
```

Answer (score 2):

My IDE told me that this expression always returns "true":

```
!period.equals(x) || !period.equals(y)
```

Let's break down why.  Using [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to simplify the logic, we arrive at this expression.

```
!(period.equals(x) && period.equals(y))
```

So even *if* `period` were to equal "AM", it would not equal "PM" and would fail the expression, thus making the statement *always* true.

If you flip your expression such that you use `&&` instead:

```
!period.equals(x) && !period.equals(y)
```

DeMorgan's laws state:

```
!(period.equals(x) || period.equals(y))
```

...which is more of what we want.  It's either not "AM" or it's not "PM".

Comment: +1 for De Morgan's Laws. I tried to keep the explanation simple but using this approach would help greatly if the logic was more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code, is that the terminating condition you give to your **while** loop, is:

**if** *user input* **is not-equal** to *X* **OR** *Y*, then keep spinning (*don't exit loop*).

That condition should be changed to:

```
while(!period.equals(x) && !period.equals(y));
```

In a `while()` loop, the condition for that loop is checked first. So, if the condition you enter for that loop is **true**, then the code inside it, will be executed. If the condition is **false**, then the code will not be executed.

In a `do-while()` loop, the code will be executed **first** and the condition will be checked **after** that code is executed **AT LEAST ONCE**.